# ASP.NET Mvc show element to owner of post?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, comparison

I m comparing, if current user is owner of post or owner of profile like below.

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
      if (Users.IsInRole("Admin") || (Guid)System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey == Model.UserId)
      {
          @Html.ActionLink("EditProfile", "EditProfile", "UserProfile")
      }
}
```

Is this the best way or Are there any better ways to control this comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is business logic. I would not put this check in a view.

One step better would be to have the check done in the controller, which then sets a boolean parameter of the viewmodel.

Better yet would be to run the check in some kind of business layer that the controller can query.

As for the view, perhaps there are other situations in which you want to present the edit option (e.g. the user is an administrator). By keeping the views dumb you maximize their re-usability:

```
@if(Model.ShowEditLink){
    @Html.ActionLink("EditProfile", "EditProfile", "UserProfile")
}
```

Comment: You mean for example add `if(Model.IsCurrentUser) //add edit button` statement to view after adding bool field to model in controller. Right?

Comment: Could you write example code in view side.

Comment: Yes. But perhaps there are other situations in which you want to present the edit options (e.g. the user is an administrator), so perhaps you write it, more generically, `if(Model.ShowEditLink)`. I would prefer that the view doesn't have to know *why* (semantically) it is showing the option; it just shows the option if it is told to do so. By keeping the views *dumb* you maximize their re-usability.